# "Number of rows must be a positive integer" error when ploting in Python

Tags: python

I am running code line by line as listed in [this page](https://hddm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_basic_hddm.html), when I run

```
m.plot_posterior_predictive(figsize=(14, 10))
```

python gives error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A1\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-16-916850d95b91>", line 1, in <module>
    m.plot_posterior_predictive(figsize=(14, 10))
  File "C:\Users\A1\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\hddm-0.9.7-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\hddm\models\base.py", line 1487, in plot_posterior_predictive
    kabuki.analyze.plot_posterior_predictive(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\A1\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\kabuki\analyze.py", line 556, in plot_posterior_predictive
    ax = fig.add_subplot(np.ceil(nrows), columns, subj_i+1)
  File "C:\Users\A1\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 772, in add_subplot
    ax = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **pkw)
  File "C:\Users\A1\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.set_subplotspec(SubplotSpec._from_subplot_args(fig, args))
  File "C:\Users\A1\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 597, in _from_subplot_args
    gs = GridSpec._check_gridspec_exists(figure, rows, cols)
  File "C:\Users\A1\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 225, in _check_gridspec_exists
    return GridSpec(nrows, ncols, figure=figure)
  File "C:\Users\A1\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 387, in __init__
    height_ratios=height_ratios)
  File "C:\Users\A1\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 50, in __init__
    f"Number of rows must be a positive integer, not {nrows!r}")
ValueError: Number of rows must be a positive integer, not 5.0
```

I am new to python, and has no idea about this error. Does anyone give any suggestion to run the code and output figures like [this](https://hddm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/tutorial_basic_hddm_25_0.png)?

I am using Python 3.7 in Anaconda3, and the hddm version is 0.9.7.

---

---

These are codes I have written so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import hddm
data = hddm.load_csv('cavanagh_theta_nn.csv')
m = hddm.HDDM(data)
m.find_starting_values()
m.sample(2000, burn=20)
m.plot_posterior_predictive(figsize=(14, 10))
```

---

---

Thank you for the reply, but when I trying to install the kabuki through

```
pip install git+https://github.com/hddm-devs/kabuki
```

it output another error:

```
(py37) C:\Users\A1>pip install git+https://github.com/hddm-devs/kabuki
Collecting git+https://github.com/hddm-devs/kabuki
  Cloning https://github.com/hddm-devs/kabuki to c:\users\A1\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-vkftarxg
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/hddm-devs/kabuki 'C:\Users\A1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-vkftarxg'
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hddm-devs/kabuki/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 21097 ms: Timed out
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/hddm-devs/kabuki 'C:\Users\A1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-vkftarxg' did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 128
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/hddm-devs/kabuki 'C:\Users\A1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-vkftarxg' did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 128
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have written thus far?

Comment: This is a problem with the kabuki package and seems to have been fixed [here](https://github.com/hddm-devs/kabuki/commit/9d72f53e96234973b1a4663ab14f75ef8534db88).  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to have been a new release version of kabuki on PyPI since that fix was made. So, you might have to either install kabuki yourself or edit your installed version locally.

Comment: There are instructions on installing the latest version of kabuki from the github repo [here](https://hddm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But how can I edit the installed version locally (sorry for my persistent questions)?